# SQL Server group by absorb null and empty values

Tags: sql-server, group-by, sql-server-2012, grouping, sql-null

I have this data:

```
Id  Name     amount    Comments 
-------------------------------
1     n1     421762    Hello    
2     n2        421    Bye      
3     n2        262    null     
4     n2       5127    ''
```

Each name may or may not have extra rows with null or empty comments.

How can I group by name and sum(amount) such that it ignores/absorbs the null or empty comments in the grouping and shows me only 2 groups.

Output I want:

```
Id   Name     sum(amount)   Comments 
------------------------------------
1     n1         421762     Hello    
2     n2           5180     Bye
```

I can't figure this out.

I hoped that would ignore the null/empty values but I always end up with 4 groups

```
select id, name, sum(amount), comments 
from table 
group by id, name, comments
```

Comment: You're grouping by comments too. If you *don't* want that, don't add `comments` in the `group by` clause

Comment: just add a having clause after the group by

Comment: i want to show comments in the final select statement

Comment: Is there a reason you aren't just eliminating them? `where comments is not null and comments <> ''`

Comment: @heyNow *which* comments? All of them? Some of them? You can use `STRING_AGG` in SQL Server 2017 to aggregate (concatenate) strings just as you would use eg `SUM()` on a numeric field. Or you can use MIN/MAX to return the first/last comment

Comment: @heyNow which ID do you want to display? Your desired output shows you want to retrieve the minimum ID per name. Is that what you want?

Comment: Edited question. I'm using sql-server-2012. Each name may or may not have extra rows with null or empty comments. Id isn't really that important

Comment: @heyNow `Each name may or may not have extra rows` meaning? What happens if there are three different comments for a single name and one of them is a null? Do you want to display only *one* comment? All comments?

Comment: sorry that part should have been clearer, there will only be either (1 comment and/or null/blank comment) per name, not multiple different non-null comments

Comment: @heyNow in which case a simple `MAX(comment), MIN(ID)` will be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have a field in the `SELECT` statement unless it's part of the GROUP BY clause or used for aggregation. The question and desired output shows that the rows should be grouped by name, which means all other fields (ID,amount, comments) should be aggregated.

The question doesn't specify *how* the IDs should be aggregated, or which comments should appear. Aggregating strings is only possible using functions like MIN/MAX in all SQL Server versions up to 2016. SQL Server 2017 added [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to concatenate strings. In earlier versions people have to use one of many string aggregation techniques that may involve XML or SQLCLR functions.

In SQL Server versions the desired output can be produced by

```
SELECT MIN(ID) as ID,name,sum(amount) as Amount, max(comment) as comments
from #table1 
group by name
```

This produces the desired output :

```
ID  name    Amount  comments
1   n1      421762  Hello
2   n2      5810    Bye
```

This assumes that there is only one non-empty comment. The question doesn't specify something different though.

In SQL Server 2017 multiple comments can be concatenated with STRING_AGG :

```
SELECT MIN(ID) as ID,name,sum(amount) as Amount, STRING_AGG(comment,' ') as comments
from table1 
group by name
```

Given the question's data, this will also produce the desired output.

```
ID  name    Amount  comments
1   n1      421762  Hello
2   n2      5810    Bye
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `MAX()` with `comments`:

```
select id, name, sum(amount), MAX(comments) 
from table 
group by id, name;
```

Answer (score 1):

use `row_number()`

```
  select id,name,comments,amount from 
     (select id,name,
     row_number() over(partition by Name  order by  case when Comments is not null then 1 else 2 end) rn,
       sum(amount) over(partition by Name) as amount,comments
   from table_name
      ) a where a.rn=1
```

Comment: This *doesn't* produce the desired output. The amount should be summed

Answer (score 1):

```
Select Top 1 with Ties
       ID 
      ,Name
      ,Amount = sum(Amount) over (Partition By Name)
      ,Comments = max(Comments) over (Partition By Name)
from YourTable
Order by Row_Number() over (Partition By Name Order by ID)
```

**Returns**

```
ID  Name    Amount  Comments
1   n1      421762  Hello
2   n2      5810    Bye
```