# Group by absorb NULL unless it's the only value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to group by a primary column and a secondary column. I want to ignore NULL in the secondary column unless it's the only value.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #tempx1 ( Id INT, [Foo] VARCHAR(10), OtherKeyId INT );
INSERT INTO #tempx1 ([Id],[Foo],[OtherKeyId]) VALUES
(1, 'A', NULL),
(2, 'B', NULL),
(3, 'B', 1),
(4, 'C', NULL),
(5, 'C', 1),
(6, 'C', 2);
```

I'm trying to get output like

```
Foo OtherKeyId
A   NULL
B   1
C   1
C   2
```

[This question is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55027780/sql-server-group-by-absorb-null-and-empty-values), but takes the MAX of the column I want, so it ignores other non-NULL values and won't work.

I tried to work out something based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59123060/max-only-null-value-and-group-the-others-sql-server), but I don't quite understand what that query does and can't get my output to work

```sql
-- Doesn't include Foo='A', creates duplicates for 'B' and 'C'
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY [Foo] ORDER BY [OtherKeyId]) rn1
    FROM #tempx1
)
SELECT c1.[Foo], c1.[OtherKeyId], c1.rn1
FROM cte c1
INNER JOIN cte c2 ON c2.[OtherKeyId] = c1.[OtherKeyId] AND c2.rn1 = c1.rn1
```

This is for a modern SQL Server: Microsoft SQL Server 2019

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `GROUP BY` expression with `HAVING` clause like below one

```
SELECT [Foo],[OtherKeyId]
  FROM #tempx1 t
 GROUP BY [Foo],[OtherKeyId]
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN [OtherKeyId] IS NULL THEN 0 END) IS NULL
    OR ( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM #tempx1 WHERE [Foo] = t.[Foo] ) = 1
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=567e780bd0aa83c0dcbcdea82f744da0)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Hmmm . . . I think you want filtering:

```
select t.*
from #tempx1 t
where t.otherkeyid is not null or
      not exists (select 1
                  from #tempx1 t2
                  where t2.foo = t.foo and t2.otherkeyid is not null
                 );
```

Answer (score 0):

My actual problem is a bit more complicated than presented here, I ended up using the idea from Barbaros Özhan solution to count the number of items. This ends up with two inner queries on the data set with two different `GROUP BY`. I'm able to get the results I need on my real dataset using a query like the following:

```sql
SELECT
    a.[Foo],
    b.[OtherKeyId]
FROM (
    SELECT
        [Foo],
        COUNT([OtherKeyId]) [C]
    FROM #tempx1 t
    GROUP BY [Foo]
) a
JOIN (
    SELECT
        [Foo],
        [OtherKeyId]
    FROM #tempx1 t
    GROUP BY [Foo], [OtherKeyId]
) b ON b.[Foo] = a.[Foo]
WHERE
    (b.[OtherKeyId] IS NULL AND a.[C] = 0)
    OR (b.[OtherKeyId] IS NOT NULL AND a.[C] > 0)
```